# Area 51 login no longer redirects nor logs in

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51, login

For a long time, Area 51 has required a separate login process even after one has logged in to the rest of the network. One would click on the "log in" button in the header on Area51 and then be told to wait for a redirection back. That redirection is no longer working. Instead, I see a static page that looks like this:

> Completing log in to Area 51
>
> You will be redirected automatically

Even after waiting a whole minute, there is no change, and attempting to navigate back to https://area51.stackexchange.com/ shows that I am still not logged in there.

- Microsoft Windows 8.1
- Mozilla Firefox 75.0 64 Bit

Comment: No repro Chrome: 80.0.3987.149 64 Bit, Firefox 74.0 64 Bit over windows 10.

Comment: I can't think of why it'd matter here, but just in case... do you have any ad blockers or userscripts running?

Comment: Also, cookies might be blocked.

Comment: I hit the same issue after resetting my password (Chrome 81, Linux Mint 19.3).